# Naming boolean field that is a verb

Tags: java, naming

In Java, by convention getter and setter for boolean fields will be `isField()` and `setField()`. This works perfectly fine with field names that are adjectives like `active`, `visible`, `closed`, etc.

But how do I name a field that has meaning of a verb, like `haveChildren`? Add “_ing” to the verb (`havingChildren`), maybe?

To clarify, I don't have control of the method names (getter and setter) as they are auto-generated by the IDE. So what I need is an appropriate field name so that when the IDE generate a getter for it, it make senses. For example, `hasChildren` is a perfect field name, but when the IDE generate the getter for the field it would be `isHasChildren`. How do I solve this?

Comment: If this is a bool field, `parent` would work.

Comment: If you can get away with inverting the meaning, 'childless' would to the trick.

Comment: Seems kind of silly to have to jump through hoops regarding the name of a field in order to avoid a grammatical issue caused by the IDE. Regardless, here are some additional suggestions, though I think the ones already given by others are better: isAllowedChildren, isNotEmpty, isContainer, isLeaf,

Comment: childless seems to be the way to go. Problem with parent is  I already have a parent field to hold the reference to the parent object. I think what I need is a general rule to convert the all verbs to adjectives for boolean fields.

Comment: I agree with @dnhang that you shouldn't let an IDE dictate things like this. Choosing variable and method names is important to make your code readable, which IDE it is written in should be irrelevant.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Using `parent` for this purpose is a bad choice, IMHO. I'd expect this to be a pointer/reference to the parent *object*, not a boolean flag telling me whether this thing actually `hasChildren`. Which in turn seems redundant to me, unless it is a function or calculated property - because there is very likely a `List<Object> children` somewhere, that holds exactly that information already.

Comment: @dnhang: How do you navigate from the instance in question to one of its childs (given there are any)?

Answer (score 11):

**Short answer:**

- method names aren't supossed to reflect internal implementation but expected behavior.

**Long answer:**

`haveChildren()` should be named `hasChildren()`.

Also I don't see `hasChildren()` as necessarily being the getter for a boolean class member. I guess such a method would find out whether or not a member of type `Collection` is empty.

Default name an IDE gives to generated getters and setters aren't supossed to be a law set in stone.

Another point: **Interfaces have names for yet-to-be-implemented methods.**

**If method names were supossed to reflect internal implementation, how would someone be able to ever design an interface ?** Interfaces don't have an implementation nor they know beforehand what the implementators will do under the hood.

Take for example the `Iterator` interface in Java.

When you implement `Iterator`, even when you have a boolean member named `next`, you are not supossed to rename `hasNext()` to `isNext()` or `isHavingNext()`. That's an implementation detail. In fact, I've implemented `Iterator` and what I do is have a member of the type of whathever my class has a list of, named `next` (not a boolean). `hasNext()` then returns `next!=null`.

Also, see this:

```
class patient {
      private boolean hasPulse;
      private boolean isBreathing:
      public boolean isDead(){ return (!hasPulse & !isBreathing);}
}
```

Note that `isDead()` is no normal getter.

Take IDEs' productivity tools for what they are.

Comment: isn't this even more naturally to read? isDead() {return (!hasPulse & !isBreathing);}

Comment: @gebbissimo Indeed it is.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest renaming the field to `parent` so that the getter will be `isParent` and setter will be `setParent`.

You can also try `childPresent` for the variable name and `isChildPresent` and `setChildPresent` as the getter and setter.

Comment: Same idea as Yannis's comment above but the problem is I already have a `parent` field to hold the reference to the parent object. I think what I need is a general rule to convert the all verbs to adjectives for boolean fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could put `does` before the verb. Such as `doesHaveChildren` in your example you provided. Or perhaps `shouldHaveChildren` depending on the context.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have control of the method name because the getter and setter are auto-generated by the IDE (e.g. Eclipse).

Comment: Just rename the method(s)? Add a keybind to rename methods (if you haven't got one already).

Comment: @dnhang if it's your code, you can call the methods whatever you like, regardless of what the IDE calls them when it auto-generates.

Comment: @miguel.martin One reason you wouldn't want to do this is Java-beans. The assumption of `isSomething` is a part of that specification and many assumptions are made around it, for better or worse, going against this with `doesSomething` can an will break things in not so obvious ways, leading to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The question is perfectly reasonable. Sometimes renaming the auto-generated method is not enough. Example: JSF managed beans are expected to have `isXyz()` as the getter method of a `boolean xyz` property.

I agree with BlackPanther who suggests renaming the field to `parent` and using `isParent` as the method name. Per the information hiding principle, getter and setter methods' readability is more important than the attribute's.